# Is Anatta a phenomenon?

Tags: anatman

Sabbe Dhamma Anatta. It means all conditioned and unconditioned phenomena are not-self.

Is not-self or Anatta a phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanings of the word 'dhamma' are very broad. The root meaning of the word 'dhamma' is 'that which supports'.

> The word dharma has roots in the Sanskrit dhr-, which means to hold or
> to support, and is related to Latin firmus (firm, stable). From this,
> it takes the meaning of "what is established or firm", and hence
> "law". It is derived from an older Vedic Sanskrit n-stem dharman-,
> with a literal meaning of "bearer, supporter", in a religious sense
> conceived as an aspect of Rta.
>
> In the Rigveda, the word appears as an n-stem, dhárman-, with a range
> of meanings encompassing "something established or firm" (in the
> literal sense of prods or poles). Figuratively, it means "sustainer"
> and "supporter" (of deities). It is semantically similar to the Greek
> themis ("fixed decree, statute, law").
>
> [Wikipeadia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma#Etymology)

Therefore, anatta is certainly a 'dhamma'. [AN 3.136](https://suttacentral.net/an3.136/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin) says:

> Whether Realized Ones arise or not, this law of nature persists, this
> regularity of natural principles, this invariance of natural
> principles:
>
> Uppādā vā, bhikkhave, tathāgatānaṁ anuppādā vā tathāgatānaṁ ṭhitāva sā
> dhātu **dhamma**ṭṭhitatā **dhamma**niyāmatā.
>
> all things are not-self.
>
> Sabbe **dhammā** anattā.

While the word 'dhamma' is used [AN 3.136](https://suttacentral.net/an3.136/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin) is in relation to 'natural law', it is a 'dhamma' because the wisdom/understanding of anatta as natural law 'supports' liberation from suffering.

Whether the English word 'phenomenon' is relevant here is subject to discussion/debate. Buddhism is not really about English words. Buddhism says anatta is a characteristic (lakkhana) of everything. Whether a 'characteristic' is a 'phenomena' in English I do not know.

In summary, anatta is certainly a dhamma because it supports/upholds liberation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I likely misled you with my previous answer (see below). To be honest I'm not sure, but I would consider this:

*sabbe dhamma anatta* = 'all phenomena are anatta' **or** 'all phenomena are not atta'

So we can surely say, atta is not phenomena. Then the negation of atta (anatta) is phenomena - anything you would call phenomena is described by anatta.

<s>Personally I think it is a negation of atta, so that is the non-perception of atta, so not phenomena but empty
phenomena</s>

Comment: Yes. Seems to be correct.

Comment: I think Anatta is Nibbana. Unconditioned phenomena.

Comment: i think nibbana is closer to atta - unborn, unmade, unconditioned, etc